# Keep window maximized wpf

Tags: wpf, window

I need a window to stay maximized, so I use WindowState="Maximized" and ResizeMode="NoResize"> but the user can minimize it by trying to drag the window. Is there any way to disable it?

Comment: Generally if you want the screen to stay maximised then you want it to be full screen as this removes all the grab bars used to change the size or move the window, the assumption being that if you leave these controls there you want to use them setting WindowStyle to None removes these

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting WindowStyle="None".

Comment: But then I can't use the X button to close the window

Comment: Create an X button or exit or home button. In the button event, call this.close() method to close the window.